# How do I constrain a turret's movements?

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a turret I want to constrain rotation with the turret rotating and facing the mouse, so it doesn't go over the maximum rotation and stops rotating if you reach the maximum point. and does not go lower than minimum degrees when it reaches minimum degrees, but the max and min angles change depending on the side the mouse is facing.

When the mouse goes on the right side of the turret, aka mouseX is greater than turret's x position.
the turret will change scaleX and the turret turns to the right and has constrained aiming rotation between 120 degrees and -160.

when the turret faces left, aka the mouseX is less than the turret's x position. the turret will switch scaleX and turn to the left. then, the constrained aiming rotation switches to between 70 degrees and -20 degerees.

Here is my code, I'm new to calculating rotations and degrees so I think I got it completely wrong, because the turret doesn't rotate at all unless i remove the code. I need help on fixing the code. Thanks!

```
function update(e:Event)
{
    //make the turret face the mouse
    if (parent != null)
    {
        var dx = parent.mouseX - x;
        var dy = parent.mouseY - y;
        var angle = Math.atan2(dy, dx)/Math.PI * 180;

    //this is supposed to constrain the rotation if the mouse is bigger than turret's x 
    //position, else constrain it the other way, this part of the code doesnt work.
    //this code makes it so the turret is unable rotate at all
    //if i remove the code, the turret can rotate freely though.
    if(mouseX > x)
    {
        angle=Math.min(angle,120);
        angle=Math.max(angle,-160);

    } 
    else 
    {
        angle=Math.min(angle,-20);
        angle=Math.max(angle,70);

    }       
        rotation = angle;
    }
}
```

Comment: where did you declared mouseX as variable? Do you have Flash Debugger?

Comment: angle.Math.min(angle,120) seems to have a typo (should be = instead of .)

Comment: Make sure to install Flash Debugger so your browser tells you when this kind of error happens. Google Chrome needs an extra step to turn on Flash Debugger

Comment: @brennanyoung, thanks for letting me know about the typo, however the code still doesn't work and the turret won't rotate.

Comment: @MarcoAurélioDeleu I'm not sure if I have to declare a variable for mouseX, it does show up as a keyword in flash and mouseX seems to work without declaring it. And no I don't have flash debugger.

Comment: Here is the problem with not having the debugger: Whenever you make a mistake that is **compillable** you won't know the problem. In this case all you have to say is that you don't see what you expected to see, but you can't tell us the error message because you don't have the Debugger. With the debugger you will be able to see why the turret is not turning over if the problem is a typo or a variable not declared or any sort of problems like that.

Comment: Okay I tried debugging now. It seems like I got no errors. Nothing showed up at all.

Comment: BTW, it's not tremendously useful to use project-specific terminology such as "turret" when posing questions here.

We can work out (in this case) that you mean a 2D object which rotates, but it could just as well have been a 3D object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't specified how `update` is being called. If it's called by (say) a mouse move event, you can get the mouse coords directly from the event.

Here is another version which works for me using that technique. Script is in the timeline of the 'turret' movieclip.

```
function update(e:MouseEvent)
{
    //make the turret face the mouse
    if (parent != null)
    {
        var dx = e.stageX - x;
        var dy = e.stageY - y;
        var angle = Math.atan2(dy,dx) / Math.PI * 180;

        //this is supposed to constrain the rotation if the mouse is bigger than turret's x 
        //position, else constrain it the other way, this part of the code doesnt work.
        //this code makes it so the turret is unable rotate at all
        //if i remove the code, the turret can rotate freely though.
        if (mouseX > x)
        {
            angle = Math.min(angle,120);
            angle = Math.max(angle,-160);

        }
        else
        {
            angle = Math.min(angle,-20);
            angle = Math.max(angle,70);

        }
        rotation = angle;
    }
}

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, update);
```